# Mortarboard Badge earned only once although i reached the 200 reputation for multiple days

Tags: support, status-bydesign, badges

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [List of all badges with full descriptions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions)

I haven't earned the Mortarboard Badge for the last time, although i reached 200 reputation for multiple days. How this badge is awarded?

Comment: Mortarboard is only awarded once, that's [status-bydesign]. When you hit the rep cap 150 times, you'll get the gold [Legendary](http://stackoverflow.com/badges/146/legendary).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That's how it's supposed to be. Mortarboard is only awarded once, the first time you reach 200 reputation in one day.

Doing it multiple times eventually nets you two other badges:

- [Epic](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/51/epic) for reaching 200 rep 50 times;
- [Legendary](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/146/legendary) for reaching 200 rep 150 times.

See also: [List of all badges with full descriptions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions).